# Improving the speed of evaluating numerical solution to a sytem of PDE

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, numerical-integration, physics, nonlinear

I am running a simulation for a kinetic reaction inside a pellet modeled by a system fo reaction-diffusion equations.

```
δ = 0.001;
{de, kgco2, kgh2, kgmeoh, kgh2o, kgco} = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
radius = 0.01;
r = 8.314;
rho = 8960;
```

Then, a series of diffusion equations:

```
e6 = rho*(-r1[x, w] - r2[x, w]) + (de*((2*Derivative[1][psco2][x])/x + 
    Derivative[2][psco2][x]))/(r*radius^2*tp[w]) == 0;
e7 = rho*(-3*r1[x, w] - r2[x, w]) + (de*((2*Derivative[1][psh2][x])/x + 
    Derivative[2][psh2][x]))/(r*radius^2*tp[w]) == 0; 
e8 = -(rho*r1[x, w]) + (de*((2*Derivative[1][psmeoh][x])/x + 
    Derivative[2][psmeoh][x]))/(r*radius^2*tp[w]) == 0;
e9 = rho*(r1[x, w] + r2[x, w]) + (de*((2*Derivative[1][psh2o][x])/x + 
    Derivative[2][psh2o][x]))/(r*radius^2*tp[w]) == 0;
e10 = rho*r2[x, w] + (de*((2*Derivative[1][psco][x])/x + 
    Derivative[2][psco][x]))/(r*radius^2*tp[w]) == 0;
```

They are accompanied by the following boundary conditions:

```
ei1 = Derivative[1][psco2][δ] == 0;
ei2 = Derivative[1][psh2][δ] == 0;
ei3 = Derivative[1][psmeoh][δ] == 0;
ei4 = Derivative[1][psh2o][δ] == 0;
ei5 = Derivative[1][psco][δ] == 0;
ei6 = -de*Derivative[1][psco2][1] == kgco2*(psco2[1] - pco2[w]);
ei7 = -de*Derivative[1][psh2][1] == kgh2*(psh2[1] - ph2[w]);
ei8 = -de*Derivative[1][psmeoh][1] == kgmeoh*(psmeoh[1] - pmeoh[w]);
ei9 = -de*Derivative[1][psh2o][1] == kgh2o*(psh2o[1] - ph2o[w]);
ei10 = -de*Derivative[1][psco][1] == kgco*(psco[1] - pco[w]);
```

With a complicated kinetic function:

```
r1[x_, w_] := (k5k2k3k4kh2[tp[w]]*psco2[x]*psh2[x]*(1 - 
    1/kstar[tp[w]]*(psh2o[x]*psmeoh[x])/(psh2[x]^3*psco2[x])))/(1 + 
    kh2ok8[tp[w]]*psh2o[x]/psh2[x] + rootkh2[tp[w]]*Sqrt[psh2[x]] + 
    kh2o[tp[w]]*psh2o[x])^3;
```

As well as:

```
r2[x_, w_] := (k1[tp[w]]*
    psco2[x]*(1 - k3[tp[w]]*(psh2o[x]*psco[x])/(psh2[x]*psco2[x])))/(
    1 + kh2ok8[tp[w]]*psh2o[x]/psh2[x] + rootkh2[tp[w]]*Sqrt[psh2[x]] + 
    kh2o[tp[w]]*psh2o[x]);
```

The k parameters are defined:

```
k5k2k3k4kh2[t_] := 1.07*Exp[36696/(r*t)];
rootkh2[t_] := 0.499*Exp[17197/(r*t)];
kh2o[t_] := 6.62*10^-11*Exp[124119/(r*t)];
kh2ok8[t_] := 3453.38;
k1[t_] := 1.22*10^10*Exp[-94765/(r*t)];
kstar[t_] := 10^(3589/t - 11.2);
k3[t_] := 10^(2067/t - 2.0);
```

With dummy functions:

```
tp[w_] := 273 + 210;
pco2[w_] := 1;
ph2[w_] := 1;
pmeoh[w_] := 1;
ph2o[w_] := 1;
pco[w_] := 1;
```

The system is solved through:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{e6, e7, e8, e9, e10, ei1, ei2, ei3, ei4, ei5,
ei6, ei7, ei8, ei9, ei10}, {psco2, psh2, psmeoh, psh2o, 
psco}, {x, δ, 1}, {w}]
```

Mathematica accepts this system but when I try to obtain a solution:

```
Plot[psco2[10][x] /. sol, {x, δ, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The computation takes forever. Is there a way to improve the speed of this computation ?

Comment: `w` is an internal (dummy) variable in your expressions. It does not appear anywhere in the final equations you pass to `ParametricNDSolve`.  That aside my advice is to first demonstrate that `NDSolve` works for a particular parameter, before working with `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: Another suggestion is to try to formulate this as an initial value problem, (all b.c. at `delta` ).  Do that to prove out the consistency of your system, then approach the boundary value problem, which will likely require specifying `StartingInitialConditions`

Comment: Try `Plot[Evaluate[psco2[10][x] /. sol],....]`

Comment: The first steps to improving speed are to eliminate `w` and replace `ParametricNDSolve` by `NDSolve`, replace `SetDelayed` by `Set` everywhere, move constants to the beginning of the computation. However, none of these actions seem to have any effect on obtaining an answer in a reasonable time.  The root cause, therefore, is the system of ODEs itself.  Consider trying the @george2079 's second recommendation.

Comment: @george2079 I am using ParametricNDSolve because my dummy functions normally depend on w, although I have surpressed the dependence in this example in order to simplify the computation. I'm afraid I don't understand your suggestion about initial value problem, could you elaborate?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Could you explain what difference it makes to use Set instead of SetDelayed ?

Comment: @user21 This does not seem to help I'am afraid.

Comment: if you don't know the terms initial value  and boundary value problem you need to. (You have posed a boundary value problem). This is a good start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method.  In short, delete conditions 6-10 and specify (guess) initial (at delta) values for your 5 functions. Make sure that works before tackling the real problem you want to solve.  Also my feeling `ParametricNDSolve` is appropriate for problems that can be solved quickly. Obviously not so here. Just use `NDSolve` and tabulate results for specific `w` values.

Comment: In answer to your question about `SetDelayed`, `tp = 273 + 210` gives `tp` the value `483` when that line of code is encountered, but `tp[w_] := 273 + 210` gives `tp` does the arithmetic every time `tp[w]` is encountered, which could be thousands of times.  So, avoid `SetDelayed` unless it is truly needed, and it isn't here.  Unfortunately, such "good housekeeping" does not seem to help much here.

Comment: I just verified that converting this to an initial value problem produces a solution (exponential growth) very quickly.  But, even  one boundary condition at `x = 1` prevents a timely solution.  I find this surprising.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Could you show me what code you are using, to get me started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Attempt**

The following is a partial answer.  It entails

1. Eliminating `w` and replaced `ParametricNDSolve` by `NDSolve`
2. Replacing `SetDelayed` by `Set` everywhere
3. Moving constants to the beginning of the computation
4. Replacing `Sqrt[psh2[x]]` by `Sqrt[Abs[psh2[x]]]`
5. Introducing `xmax` as the upper limit of integration
6. Successfully obtaining an answer for `xmax = .1`
7. Explicitly using the "Shooting" `Method`
8. Gradually increasing `xmax`, using "StartingInitialConditions" obtained from calculations with smaller `xmax`.

(The first three improve speed modestly but otherwise are not important.)  I am stalled at `xmax = .75`.  Here is the code and results.

```
δ = 0.001; xmax = .75;
{de, kgco2, kgh2, kgmeoh, kgh2o, kgco} = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
radius = 0.01;
r = 8.314;
rho = 8960;

tp = 273 + 210;
pco2 = 1;
ph2 = 1;
pmeoh = 1;
ph2o = 1;
pco = 1;

k5k2k3k4kh2[t_] = 1.07*Exp[36696/(r*t)];
rootkh2[t_] = 0.499*Exp[17197/(r*t)];
kh2o[t_] = 6.62*10^-11*Exp[124119/(r*t)];
kh2ok8[t_] = 3453.38;
k1[t_] = 1.22*10^10*Exp[-94765/(r*t)];
kstar[t_] = 10^(3589/t - 11.2); 
k3[t_] = 10^(2067/t - 2.0);

e6 = rho*(-r1[x] - r2[x]) + (de*((2*Derivative[1][psco2][x])/x + 
    Derivative[2][psco2][x]))/(r*tp*radius^2) == 0;
e7 = rho*(-3*r1[x] - r2[x]) + (de*((2*Derivative[1][psh2][x])/x + 
    Derivative[2][psh2][x]))/(r*tp*radius^2) == 0;
e8 = -(rho*r1[x]) + (de*((2*Derivative[1][psmeoh][x])/x + 
    Derivative[2][psmeoh][x]))/(r*tp*radius^2) == 0;
e9 = rho*(r1[x] + r2[x]) + (de*((2*Derivative[1][psh2o][x])/x + 
    Derivative[2][psh2o][x]))/(r*tp*radius^2) == 0;
e10 = rho*r2[x] + (de*((2*Derivative[1][psco][x])/x + 
    Derivative[2][psco][x]))/(r*tp*radius^2) == 0;

ei1 = Derivative[1][psco2][δ] == 0;
ei2 = Derivative[1][psh2][δ] == 0;
ei3 = Derivative[1][psmeoh][δ] == 0;
ei4 = Derivative[1][psh2o][δ] == 0;
ei5 = Derivative[1][psco][δ] == 0;
ei6 = -de*Derivative[1][psco2][xmax] == kgco2*(psco2[xmax] - pco2);
ei7 = -de*Derivative[1][psh2][xmax] == kgh2*(psh2[xmax] - ph2);
ei8 = -de*Derivative[1][psmeoh][xmax] == kgmeoh*(psmeoh[xmax] - pmeoh);
ei9 = -de*Derivative[1][psh2o][xmax] == kgh2o*(psh2o[xmax] - ph2o);
ei10 = -de*Derivative[1][psco][xmax] == kgco*(psco[xmax] - pco);

r1[x_] := (k5k2k3k4kh2[tp]*psco2[x]*psh2[x]*(1 - 1/kstar[tp]*(psh2o[x]*psmeoh[x])/
    (psh2[x]^3*psco2[x])))/(1 + kh2ok8[tp]*psh2o[x]/psh2[x] + rootkh2[tp]
    *Sqrt[Abs[psh2[x]]] + kh2o[tp]*psh2o[x])^3;
r2[x_] := (k1[tp]*psco2[x]*(1 - k3[tp]*(psh2o[x]*psco[x])/(psh2[x]*psco2[x])))/
  (1 + kh2ok8[tp]*psh2o[x]/psh2[x] + rootkh2[tp]*Sqrt[Abs[psh2[x]]] + kh2o[tp]*psh2o[x]);

sol = NDSolve[{e6, e7, e8, e9, e10, ei1, ei2, ei3, ei4, ei5, ei6, ei7,
    ei8, ei9, ei10}, {psco2, psh2, psmeoh, psh2o, psco}, {x, δ, xmax}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {ei1, ei2, ei3, ei4, ei5, 
    psco2[δ] == 1.988032083488816`, psh2[δ] == 3.044559836643407`, 
    psmeoh[δ] == 1.31253522848969`, psh2o[δ] == 0.4781146784359612`, 
    psco[δ] == 0.13082302200921797`}}];

{psco2[x], psh2[x], psmeoh[x], psh2o[x], psco[x]} /. sol /. x -> δ
(* {{2.91349, 4.60682, 1.84667, -0.913494, -0.0668281}} *)

Plot[Evaluate[{psco2[x], psh2[x], psmeoh[x], psh2o[x], psco[x]} /. sol], 
    {x, δ, xmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Ideally, knowledge of the physical problem being solved would provide good values for "StartingInitialConditions".  Even *a priori* bounds on the "StartingInitialConditions" would be helpful to discourage "Shooting" from sampling the wrong regions of solution space.

**Addendum: Full Solution**

```
Plot[(psh2o[x] - psco[x] + psmeoh[x]) /. sol, {x, δ, xmax}]
```

reveals that `psh2o[x] - psco[x] + psmeoh[x]` is equal to `1.` with high accuracy.  The same is true of `psco2[x] + psco[x] - psmeoh[x]` and `-psh2[x] + -psco[x] + 3 psmeoh[x]`.  In fact, this is to be expected.  A linear combination of the ODEs above yields

```
(de*((2*Derivative[1][ps][x])/x + Derivative[2][ps][x]))/(r*radius^2*tp) == 0;
```

where `ps` represents any of these three linear combinations.  When combined with corresponding boundary conditions, it yields `ps[x] -> 1`.  Thus, the ODE system can be simplified significantly by eliminating three of the five dependent variables.  With the substitution,

```
{psh2o[x] -> psco[x] - psmeoh[x], psco2[x] -> -psco[x] + psmeoh[x], 
 psh2[x] -> -psco[x] + 3 psmeoh[x]}
```

the functions `r1` and `r2` become

```
r1[x_] := (k5k2k3k4kh2[tp] (psco[x] - 3 psmeoh[x]) (psco[x] - psmeoh[x]) 
    (kstar[tp] (psco[x] - 3 psmeoh[x])^3 - psmeoh[x]))/(kstar[tp] (kh2o[tp] psco[x]^2 + 
    psmeoh[x] (-3 + kh2ok8[tp] + 3 kh2o[tp] psmeoh[x] - 3 Sqrt[Abs[psco[x] - 3 psmeoh[x]]] 
    rootkh2[tp]) + psco[x] (1 - kh2ok8[tp] - 4 kh2o[tp] psmeoh[x] + 
    Sqrt[Abs[psco[x] - 3 psmeoh[x]]] rootkh2[tp]))^3)

r2[x_] := (k1[tp] (psco[x] - psmeoh[x]) ((-1 + k3[tp]) psco[x] + 3 psmeoh[x]))/
    (kh2o[tp] psco[x]^2 + psmeoh[x] (-3 + kh2ok8[tp] + 3 kh2o[tp] psmeoh[x] - 
    3 Sqrt[Abs[psco[x] - 3 psmeoh[x]]] rootkh2[tp]) + psco[x] (1 - kh2ok8[tp] 
    - 4 kh2o[tp] psmeoh[x] + Sqrt[Abs[psco[x] - 3 psmeoh[x]]] rootkh2[tp]))
```

and the solution is provided by

```
xmax = 1;
sol1 = NDSolve[{e8, e10, ei3, ei5, ei8, ei10}, {psmeoh, psco}, {x, δ, xmax}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {ei3, ei5, 
    psmeoh[δ] == 1.2608611256607714`, psco[δ] == -0.011072222667300185`}}];
{-psco[x] + psmeoh[x], -psco[x] + 3 psmeoh[x], psmeoh[x], psco[x] - psmeoh[x], 
    psco[x]} /. sol1 /. x -> δ
(* {{1.35351, 4.023, 1.33475, -1.35351, -0.0187626}} *)
Plot[Evaluate[{-psco[x] + psmeoh[x], -psco[x] + 3 psmeoh[x], psmeoh[x], 
    psco[x] - psmeoh[x], psco[x]} /. sol1], {x, δ, xmax}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> {psco2[x], psh2[x], psmeoh[x], psh2o[x], psco[x]}]
```

[image]

That this solution differs from the earlier one (besides the fact that `xmax` is larger) should not be too surprising.  These highly nonlinear equations may have more than one solution.  Moreover, I could not extend in the least the earlier solution beyond `xmax = 3/4` despite considerable effort.  The earlier solution simply may not exist for larger `xmax`.

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest in this problem. I've been trying to reproduce your results but so far I am unsuccessful. When I naively copy the first code (first attempt) into a blank notebook, I encounter an error message:    At x == 0.08293242960370201`, step size is effectively zero; \
singularity or stiff system suspected

Comment: @Whelp  Something very strange happening here.  I shall post a fix as soon as I can.

Comment: @Whelp In the meantime, try "Full Solution" To do so, start a fresh session of Mathematica and copy into a new notebook the code from "First Attempt" up to and including ei10. Then, replace `xmax=0.75` by `xmax = 1` in the first line of the code just copied,  Next, copy the last two blocks of code (new r1 and r2 definitions and sol1 =  etc.) from "Full Solution". This works for me, and it should for you. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Whelp  Amazingly, replacing `r*radius^2*tp` by `r*tp*radius^2` solved the problem.  Apparently, the calculation in "First Attempt" is on the threshold of instability, and the difference in roundoff is sufficient to change the answer.  In any event, I urge you not to waste time on the "First Attempt" solution.  "Full Solution" addresses your needs, I believe.

Comment: Wow, that is very sensitive. Following your steps I've been able to get it to ru, this should be a very strong first step in getting this to work for the full problem. I will now have to introduce temperature dependence as well as axial location in the bed (w). In this kind of numerical simulation with a singularity at x=0, is there a way to avoid setting a δ cutoff?

Comment: @Whelp  Extraordinarily sensitive for the parameters in "First Attempt", much less so for those in "Full Solution".  Starting the computation at `x == δ` instead of `x ==0 ` typically is not a bad approach, and you can reduce the size of `δ` to verify this.  Alternatively, you can expand the ODEs in power series and use the results to obtain more accurate boundary conditions at `x == δ` from those at `x ==0 `.

Comment: After spending more time on the code I find that the simplification introduced in "full solution" has some difficulties with the boundary conditions at x=1. The variable "p" represents the partial pressure of a component, and there are some implied conservation laws as you pointed out. For example : psco2[x]=psco2[1]+psmeoh[1]+psco[1]-psmeoh[x]-psco[x]. With this replacement rule however, the code fails because the variables are no longer decoupled.